# Add HTTP authentication to embedded Jetty

Tags: jetty, wicket, jax-rs, resteasy, embedded-jetty

I'm embedding Jetty 9.1 from within a Java application. I'm configuring everything programmatically; I am *not* using `web.xml` or Spring or anything else. I have Wicket mapped to `/*` and a RestEASY JAX-RS API mapped to `/rest/*`. That's all working fine.

I wanted to add HTTP authentication, so I added the following (based upon as much Jetty documentation as I find):

```
HashLoginService loginService = new HashLoginService();
loginService.setName("My Realm");
loginService.setConfig("src/main/resources/realm.properties");
server.addBean(loginService);
```

I added a user with a role of `admin` to `realm.properties`. Then I tried to configure my REST service, putting the following annotation on my main JAX-RS resource:

```
@RolesAllowed({ "admin" })
```

Then I added the following annotation to my main Wicket page:

```
@AuthorizeInstantiation("admin")
```

None of these changes made any difference; I can still use my browser to navigate to my REST API and Wicket pages.

I'm guessing I need to turn on DIGEST authentication in Jetty. But how do I do that programmatically, without a `web.xml` file? What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9011540/421049) to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8056851/421049), providing a link to a [sample webapp](https://github.com/jesperfj/jetty-secured-sample/), helped me immensely and got me up and running.

Comment: Unfortunately, that example forces the security handler to be the only handler--it doesn't play well when you want the server to use a ResourceHandler to serve files, for example.

Comment: I haven't selected an answer yet. By all means let us know the best way!

Answer (score 1):

In Jetty v7, you chain the handlers together:

```
server.setHandler(securityHandler);
securityHandler.setHandler(resourceHandler);
```

*Works on my machine! (tm)*